# firebase get users by array of IDs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase in React.js project. Here is my question:

have firebase collection:

```
users:{
  '1JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB':{user data inside},
  '2JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB':{user data inside},
  '3JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB':{user data inside}
}
```

I have array of user iD

```
let ids = ['1JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB', '3JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB'];
```

How to get only users which id match to ids array?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!!

Answer (score -3):

You could use "for key in obj"

```
let users = yourFireBase.val(); 

let ids = ['1JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB', '3JDJDHDHDSbBDBDB'];
let matchUsersArr = [];

for (let key in users) {
   if (ids.indexOf(key)>=0) {
       matchUsersArr.push(users[key])
   }
}
```

Comment: in such case I load all users firs and than filtering out?
I have nearly 500 users...and want to load just 5 from them.